# Wordpress $wpdb->get_results not returning anything

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to pull out an array of option names from the Wordpress database of a test site I setup that I'm running in debug mode. Once I've got this part of the functionality down I intend to use it to expand upon a plugin I built.

So far in searching here and on wordpress.org it seems like the below code should be working but it isn't:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "options";
$sql = "SELECT  `option_name` FROM " . $table_name . " WHERE  `option_name` LIKE  '%Domain_%'";
$doms = $wpdb->get_results($sql, ARRAY_N); 

foreach($doms as $dom){
    echo $dom;
}
```

Every time I run the above code I get the following errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: doms in /sitepath/test.php on line 38
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /sitepath/test.php on line 38

I have several items in the option_name column of the options table that fit the query criteria and the query itself works fine in mySQL.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try with the following function `var_dump($doms)` before the `foreach` loop and paste here the output

Comment: I tried a var dump on $doms and am just getting a NULL return. As in nothing is being returned at all. I'm also trying other queries to see if they return anything and no queries are returning anything. Basically, anything I input into $wpdb->get_results returns null.

Comment: it seems that `get_results` function returns `null` if something is wrong with the query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

Comment: I think your calling `$wpdb` outside the wordpress environment. Try `var_dump` on `$wpdb` pls

Comment: Yeah, $wpdb is throwing a null when I try a var_dump on it.

Comment: try to put the following line at the beginning of your test file: `/** Make sure that the WordPress bootstrap has run before continuing. */
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
`.but be aware this is not a very elegant solution.

Comment: I just tried requiring wp-load.php but that just threw errors. I also tried requiring wp-db.php just in case but got errors over trying to re-declare the wpdb class.

Comment: Hmm, I believe I've resolved the problem. Apparently I need to stick the logic within a function in order for it to work properly. You learn something every day apparently... Thank you very much for trying to help:)